# How to display or hide div content on menu item hover (selection)

Tags: html, css, hover, display

I now have the following menu:

```
  <div class="menu">
     <a class="active" href="#resume">**Resumé**</a>
     <a href="certificates.html">**Certificates**</a>
     <a href="contact.html">**Contact**</a>
     <a href="bio.html">**Bio**</a>
  </div>
```

**Current output**: As it stands now, each of the page shown in the links displays when one clicks on the menu items above.  It works fine, but it is not very "responsive". You have to wait for the individual pages to load, and it's less than ideal. (Resume is the active menu item and always displays unless one clicks on the other selections.)

**Desired output**: If one hovers over "Certificates" for example, I would like the Resume content to disappear (hide), and have the Certificates div content appear (display) on the page, and then if one hovers over "Contact", the Certificates content should disappear, and the Contact div content should be displayed. So whenever out of focus (no hover):hide, and whenever in focus (on hover):display.

The following code is not working to show/hide the divs:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#resume">Resumé</a>
    <a href="#certs">Certificates</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#bio">Bio</a>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("a[href$='#certs']").onmouseover(function() {
    $(".resume").hide();
    $(".certs").show();
    });

    $("a[href$='#contact']").onmouseover(function() {
    $(".resume").css("display", "none");
    $(".contact").css("display", "block");
    });

    $("a[href$='#bio']").onmouseover(function() {
    $(".resume").hide();
    $(".bio").show();
    });

    $("a[href$='#resume']").onmouseover(function() {
    $(".resume").show();
    $(".certs").hide();
    $(".contact").hide();
    $(".bio").hide();
    });


    });
</script>


<div class="resume">

My script tag in the <head> tag looks as follows:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1  /jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly less than ideal to load your web page every time a user clicks a menu item. Here's one way to avoid that.

1. Put all your different html pages into one page, each one in a separate `div`.
2. On load, hide all the `div`s except the one you want to show.
3. Whenever the user clicks on a menu item, first hide all the `div`s (you can keep track of which `div` is showing and hide only that one if you prefer) and then show the one corresponding to the menu item the user clicked.

That way, you load everything up front, so that's where the performance hit is.

Comment: Thank you Bob!!  I'll give that a shot!

Comment: How do I hide .resume and put .certs in it's place when .menu a#certs:hover occurs?

Comment: @Troy Sorry, I was thinking click rather than hover. Wait a minute. You're trying to do this in pure CSS?

Comment: Yes, if that's the simplest, most straightforward way.  Otherwise, Javascript or jQuery is okay as well.

Comment: @Troy I don't think it's that simple to do it in CSS. It's difficult to change a CSS value on one element when you hover over a different one. I would use JS or jQuery, and work with the hover event.

Comment: Ok Bob.  I'll check that out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I followed BobRodes' instructions and added jQuery code based on the hover event. Before I did that, I took BobRodes' suggestion and put all the individual pages into one page, to make the site more responsive. Now, instead of each individual page having to load every time one of the menu links is clicked on, the individual div's (each div representing what used to be the individual pages) are just shown and hidden, as needed. THANK YOU BobRodes!!!

Here is the jQuery code I came up with:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".resume").show();
$(".certs").hide();
$(".contact").hide();
$(".bio").hide();

$("**a[href$='#certs'**]").hover(function() {
$(".resume").hide();
$(".contact").hide();
$(".bio").hide();
$(".certs").show();
});

$("**a[href$='#contact']**").hover(function() {
$(".resume").hide();
$(".certs").hide();
$(".bio").hide();
$(".contact").show();
});

$("**a[href$='#bio**']").hover(function() {
$(".resume").hide();
$(".certs").hide();
$(".contact").hide();
$(".bio").show();
});

$("a[href$='#resume']").hover(function() {
$(".resume").show();
$(".certs").hide();
$(".contact").hide();
$(".bio").hide();
});


});
</script>
```